# How to return false if no row has particular values using PostgreSQL or node.js?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, select

An example table would be:

```
P Q
t f
f t
f f
```

IS there a way in SQL to return false if querying for `t t` but return true if querying for `t f`,`f t` or `ff`, or should it be done with node.js by a select and then a if else for if the select returned null?

What is the optimal way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a boolean expression is ... a boolean value:

---

```
CREATE table pq
        ( p boolean NOT NULL
        , q boolean NOT NULL
        );
INSERT INTO pq ( p , q) VALUES
( False, False), ( False, True), ( True, False), ( True, True)
        ;

SELECT p, q
        , (p <> true OR q <> true) as nand
FROM pq
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 p | q | nand 
---+---+------
 f | f | t
 f | t | t
 t | f | t
 t | t | f
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT
   CASE P WHEN 't' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END,
   CASE Q WHEN 't' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
FROM Your_Table
```

or use 0, 1 insteaf:

```
SELECT
   CASE P WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
   CASE Q WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Your_Table
```